# Why are my equations hidden between two pages in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equations

I am using word office to write some math notes. Most my equations are written in tables which makes it easy to number and cite them. While the equations look nice in the middle of the page, once I add more text above them and they start going down closer to the end of the page then some equations are hidden. The equations do appear if I choose the option "Change to Inline", but then the equations are not as nice as they looked before. Is there another way to solve this problem?

**Before (middle of page)**

[image]

**After (end of page)**

[image]

Comment: This *may* help : select the table, right-click and select Table Properties..., then in the Row tab, uncheck "Allow row to break across pages".